# Qt c++ nested classes / solve illegal call of non-static member function

Tags: c++, qt, nested

I'm dealing with sample code from a camera SDK, and I have issues getting the frame data "outside" the CSampleCaptureEventHandler class.

```
class DahengCamera : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    class CSampleCaptureEventHandler : public ICaptureEventHandler
    {       
        void DoOnImageCaptured(CImageDataPointer& objImageDataPointer, void* pUserParam)
        {
            [grab some data ...]
        
            CopyToImage(objImageDataPointer);  // illegal call of non-static member function
        }

    };


public:
    DahengCamera();
    ~DahengCamera();
    
private:
   
    void CopyToImage(CImageDataPointer pInBuffer);  // I want to have my frame datas here

    QImage m_data; //and here

};
```

I'm using a callback register call to make the camera "DoOnImageCaptured" event called once a frame is grabbed by the system. But I'm stuck getting the data outside this method. CopyToImage() is supposed to get a reference to QImage or to write into m_data, but I have "illegal call of non-static member function" errors. Tried to make CopyToImage() static, but it just move the problem...

How can I solve this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CopyToImage` is a private non-static function in the class `DahengCamera`.
The fact that `CSampleCaptureEventHandler` is a nested class inside `DahengCamera` allows it to access `DahengCamera`'s private members and functions (as if it were decleared a friend class), but this does not provide `CSampleCaptureEventHandler` with a pointers to any `DahengCamera` objects.

You need to provide the actual instance of the `CSampleCaptureEventHandler` object on which `DoOnImageCaptured` is called with a pointer/refence to the `DahengCamera` object on which `CopyToImage` should be called. You might consider providing this pointer/reference to the `DoOnImageCaptured` object to `CSampleCaptureEventHandler`'s constuctor (i.e. dependency injection).

(And - for your own sake - do **not** try to "fix" this by turning `CopyToImage` or `m_data` into static - this would create only a horrible mess)

Comment: So, something like this ?

  class CSampleCaptureEventHandler : public ICaptureEventHandler
    {
        CSampleCaptureEventHandler(DahengCamera *parent)
        {
myParent = parent;
        }

        DahengCamera *myParent;
[... ]

and, in the constructor of DahengCamera :

        m_pSampleCaptureEventHandle = new CSampleCaptureEventHandler(this);    

But I don't see how to integrate this reference into CopyToImage ?

Comment: Yeah, you should then be able to call `myParent->CopyToImage(objImageDataPointer)` in `CSampleCaptureEventHandler::DoOnImageCaptured()`